# Erro ao mostrar uma String

Tags: c, string

Estou fazendo a questão [Entrada e Saída com Virgula](https://www.urionlinejudge.com.br/judge/pt/problems/view/2765), estou fazendo tudo o que a questão pediu mas estou levando 30 % de erro, poderiam me ajudar aonde o possa está o erro

Meu código

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
   char nome[100], aux_1[90], aux_2[90];
   int i = 0, cont = 0;
   scanf("%[^\n]", nome);

   for(i = 0; i < nome[i] && nome[i] != ','; i++)
   {
      aux_1[i] = nome[i];
   }
   aux_1[i] = '\0';
   i++;
   for(int j = i; j < nome[j] && nome[j] != '\0'; j++)
   {
      aux_2[cont] = nome[j];
      cont++;
   }
    aux_2[cont] = '\0';
    puts(aux_1);
    puts(aux_2);
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: O desafio fala da leitura ser feita em vários "arquivos" de teste e a saída também é em arquivo. Será que não é isso que falta?

Comment: Acabei de fazer o que você mandou coloquei com o final do arquivo EOF, porém ainda está com 30 %